# Python function definition is empty after colon, how to explain that?

Tags: python, function, semantics

I was looking into some tensorflow source code, I encountered this function definition inside callbacks.py, where there are multiple functions having nothing inside their body after the colon. However, if you write a python function like that in normal code, there's error for such case (recall that in such case we usually add `pass` in the function body to avoid such error).

Can you help explain?

In case that it's the decorator has some magic on it, I also copy what's inside the decorator at the end.

```
@doc_controls.for_subclass_implementers
def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):
    """Called at the start of an epoch.

    Subclasses should override for any actions to run. This function should
    only be called during TRAIN mode.

    Args:
        epoch: Integer, index of epoch.
        logs: Dict. Currently no data is passed to this argument for this
          method but that may change in the future.
    """

@doc_controls.for_subclass_implementers
def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
    """Called at the end of an epoch.

    Subclasses should override for any actions to run. This function should
    only be called during TRAIN mode.

    Args:
        epoch: Integer, index of epoch.
        logs: Dict, metric results for this training epoch, and for the
          validation epoch if validation is performed. Validation result
          keys are prefixed with `val_`. For training epoch, the values of
          the `Model`'s metrics are returned. Example:
          `{'loss': 0.2, 'accuracy': 0.7}`.
    """
```

The `for_subclass_implementers` decorator:

```
from typing import TypeVar
T = TypeVar("T")
_FOR_SUBCLASS_IMPLEMENTERS = "_tf_docs_tools_for_subclass_implementers"

def for_subclass_implementers(obj: T) -> T:
  setattr(obj, _DOC_IN_CURRENT_AND_SUBCLASSES, None)
  return obj
```

Btw, I also tried making a minimal implementation using the decorator pattern on a function, but the IDE (Pycharm) also shows error on such writing, as shown below:

```
from typing import TypeVar
T = TypeVar("T")
_FOR_SUBCLASS_IMPLEMENTERS = "_tf_docs_tools_for_subclass_implementers"

def for_subclass_implementers(obj: T) -> T:
    setattr(obj, _FOR_SUBCLASS_IMPLEMENTERS, None)
    return obj

@for_subclass_implementers
def empty():

def main():
    print("0")
```

[image]

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: If you mean the first snippet: they _don't_ have nothing inside the body, they have a multiline string literal (which is a valid expression and therefore a valid statement). Python [docstrings](https://peps.python.org/pep-0257/) aren't syntactically comments. But they're so clearly _there_ I'm not sure that is what you're asking.

Comment: @jonrsharpe oh yea, you are right. I just tested by adding the string doc, which actually resolved the error.